# Can't run files in Bash in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, bash, powershell, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

Error Message:

[image]

```
$ bash: cd: c:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\Projects\Work\Present" && g++ dar.cpp -o dar && c:UsersAntonio
DesktopProjectsWorkPresent"dar: No such file or directorycd "c:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\Projects\Work
\Present\" && g++ dar.cpp -o dar && "c:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\Projects\Work\Present\"dar
bash: bash:: command not found
```

I just don't get why it's showing this error if the file exists over there. 
I can freely compile and run it with PowerShell, but when I use Bash I get the error.

I am currently using Visual Studio Code with Code Runner. 
I also couldn't find anything substantial about my problem in Google so I hope I'm in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon after the word bash (or cd) is not needed. It think you want to run bash: (it should be bash). It can't find a command called bash: , so it throws the error.

For example, on my computer:

```
mamuns-computer:~ xmrashid$ bash:
-bash: bash:: command not found
mamuns-computer:~ xmrashid$ bash
bash-5.0$
```

Comment: So it's not the file which is missing ? 
But I have Git installed. Isn't this should contain bash inside ?

Comment: hi! Yes, gitbash should come with bash. But, first thing first, that colon is messing you up.